# MongoDb slow queries with Indexes

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

We have a MongoDB NoSQL Database that holds some data. Currently the DB contains 10M rows. The default _id field is used as a primary key. 
Our collection has three variables:

- _id
- Timestamp(Indexed:1)
- Variable1(Indexed:1,CompoundIndex with Timestamp)
- Variable2
- Variable3

We would like to have an query combining the Timestamp and the variable1.
We have an index on the Timestamp and Variable1. In addition, even if this is not correct for range queries we have a compound index on (Timestamp,Variable1).

No when we have queries like the following the performance is very bad(~ 1 minute execution time).

Example Query:

```
db.getCollection('XXX').find({$and:[
{timestamp:{$lte:1424195749000}},
{timestamp:{$gte:1424195649000}},
{Variable1:1}
]})
```

A query using only the Variable1 field run about on (100ms).

getIndexes():

```
{
    "0" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "XXXXXX_DB.XXXData"
    },
    "1" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "timestamp" : 1.0000000000000000
        },
        "name" : "timestamp_1",
        "ns" : "XXXXXX_DB.XXXData"
    },
    "2" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "timestamp" : -1.0000000000000000
        },
        "name" : "timestamp_-1",
        "ns" : "XXXXXX_DB.XXXData"
    },
    "3" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "variable1" : 1.0000000000000000
        },
        "name" : "variable1_1",
        "ns" : "XXXXXX_DB.XXXData"
    },
    "4" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "timestamp" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "variable1" : 1.0000000000000000
        },
        "name" : "timestamp_1_variable1_1",
        "ns" : "XXXXXX_DB.XXXData"
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? If 3.0 or higher, could you include results of [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain)?

Comment: Can you post the result of `getIndexes()` on your collection?

Comment: FWIW, when testing that at small scale with MongoDB 3.0.2, the winning plan was using the index `timestamp_1` and rejected indexes `Variable1_1` and `timestamp_1_Variable1_1`. When adding a compound index on `{Variable1: 1, timestamp:1 }`, that latter became the winner.

Comment: @marijnz0r explain already existed in earlier version. New in 3.0 is that you can use it on aggregations, but there is no aggregation query here.

Comment: @Philipp Ok cool, but you can still use it on a find query.

Answer (score 3):

You need an index on `{ Variable1: 1, timestamp: 1 }` to speed-up that query (with an upper-case **`V`** -- you use "**V**ariable1" in the query but your index seems to be on "**v**ariable1")

---

Given your query:

```
db.getCollection('XXX').find({$and:[
  {timestamp:{$lte:1424195749000}},
  {timestamp:{$gte:1424195649000}},
  {Variable1:1}
]})
```

Here, the optimizer will see that you have an *equality* on `Variable1`. So this field is the "most limiting". So the optimizer will choose an index having it as a prefix. `{ Variable: 1}` shouldn't be too bad. But `{ Variable: 1, timestamp: 1}` would be better.

Please note that you have redundant indexes:

- `{timestamp:-1}` do not add much to `{timestamp:1}`
- `{Variable1: 1}` is useless if you have `{Variable1: 1, timestamp: 1}`
  (as the former is a prefix of the later)
- `{timestamp: 1}` is useless if you have `{timestamp: 1, Variable1: 1}`
  (as the former is a prefix of the later)